# How to close tls socket connection in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, sockets, ssl

I wrote below node.js code to open a TLS connection with specified port and host.

```
var tls = require('tls');

(() => {    
     var output = {};
    const client = tls.connect({
        port: 5060,
        host: "173.99.99.99",
    }, () => {
        console.log('connected to server!');
        var cert = client.getPeerCertificate(true);
        console.log("Connection success!!!");      
    });

    client.setTimeout(1000);

    client.on('timeout',()=>{
        console.log("Requested timed out!");
        client.end();
    })
    client.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log("Data::",data);
        client.end();
    });

    client.on('error', (err) => {
        console.log('Error',err);
        client.end();
    });

    client.on('end', (op) => {
        client.destroy();
        console.log('disconnected from server',op);
    });

})();
```

And getting the output like below.

```
Requested timed out!
disconnected from server undefined
Error { Error: socket hang up
    at TLSSocket.onConnectEnd (_tls_wrap.js:1083:19)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:272:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1106:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:178:19)
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  path: undefined,
  host: '173.99.99.99',
  port: 5060,
  localAddress: undefined }
```

The expectation is, first it executes `timeout` then `end` events. But `error` event also triggered.

How can I make sure that code won't trigger `end` and `error` event on `timeout`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed socket-hang-up issue as below.

```
let client = net.createConnection({
            port: "Port",
            host: "Hostname"
        }, () => {
           //Connection is Success. Do your stuff here!!
            client.destroy();
        });

        client.setTimeout(5000);

        client.on('timeout', (data) => {
          // Connection timed-out. 
            client.destroy()
        });
        client.on('error', (err) => {
         // Something went wrong while opening.
        });
```

I'm destroying the client because after 5 seconds of opening the connection, it throws timeout and after that code will execute error block.